# How can I an animation on boolean change with jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

**Question**

How can I achieve something like a wiggle animation with jetpack compose when a boolean is changing?
From my understanding the library only supports transition animations or infinite animations. However in my case no composable object is actually changing their target value in anyway. In the examples that I found one always needs to change the target value, to actually see an animation. Like this

```kotlin
var isError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val offset = animateIntAsState(if (isError) $targetValue else 0)
// Then have something that uses the offset and add a button that is changing the state of isError
```

However I don't want the targetValue to be different from what it initially was. I just want to see a keyframes animation for example.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use the `finishedListener` parameter that comes with all `animateXAsState` functions to switch the state which triggers the animation.

Example below which adds one line to your code snippet:

```
var animationState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val xOffset: Dp by animateDpAsState(
    targetValue = if (animationState) 16.dp else 0.dp,
    finishedListener = { animationState = false }   // Add this
)
```

Comment: Well no. I don't want to repeat the same animation to go back. I just want to have one animation.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't get what you mean. This will play your animation only once, then set the state to false when done

Comment: Well yes but additionally the state change back to false triggers the animation from 16.dp to 0.dp. At least for me.